# Support for Alternate Representation of Source Map

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, web-deployment, source-maps, uglifyjs

I am familiar with javascript source maps as they provide a allow for browsers to "preimage" the minified/uglified file into the original code which is handy for debugging. For each individual source file, I can produce its respective source map and it works properly in both DevTools and IE.

However, for production the files will also be concatenated, in addition to being uglified, into just a few files. Rather than producing source maps for these large, concat files, I would like to be able to combine my existing source maps into one source map for each respective concatenation.

Enter [Index Maps](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/edit#). This seems like the perfect solution, but I do not believe either of these browsers support this alternative map option yet. Mind you, this proposal is dated Feb. 2011. Has anyone had success using this method? If so, what browser and system were you running? Did you use the "url" or "map" property of the sections field?

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion: At the moment, Chrome only supports the "map" property of the sections field. So you must place your individual source map code into the map property of its respective position/offset in the sections array.

If you would like the "url" feature supported, star the issue at the page below, to give it a higher priority.

[Chrome Issue: "url" feature support for index maps](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=552455)